# An urn has $25$ balls, of which $15$ are red and $10$ are white.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

An urn has $25$ balls, of which $15$ are red and $10$ are white. Select $5$ balls.
a. How many samples exist?
b. How many samples are all red?
c. How many samples have $3$ red?
d. How many samples have at least $4$ red?

I understand a... unfortunately, that's about it.

For a,  I got $C(25,5) = 53130$.

Comment: Hello! What solution did you come up with for A? Showing us what you tried can help us better answer your question.

Comment: Hi, i got C(25,5) = 5330

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: Ooh, I misread the question, I thought that there were 3 colors of balls.  There are only 6 samples.  There is (5 red, 0 white),  (4 red, 1 white), (3 red, 2 white), (2 red, 3 white), (1 red, 4 white), and (0 red, 5 white)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) $C(25,5)$

(b) $C(15,5)$

(c) Three balls must be red which is equal to $C(15,3)$ and two balls must be white which is equal to $C(10,2)$.  So, in total we have $C(15,3)C(10,2)$

(d) Here we must select samples with four red balls (and one white) and five red balls (and zero white).  Apply the same rule as in (b) to compute the respective number of samples and sum them up: $C(15,4)C(10,1) + C(15,5)$

Comment: well now i just feel like i was overthinking everything... Thank you!

Comment: so should it be C(15,4)C(10,1)+C(15,5)C(10,0)?

Comment: @Emilia That is correct.

Comment: @Emilia sorry for confusion -- already edited

Answer (score 0):

(5 red, 0 white) -- ${15\choose 5}$

(4 red, 1 white) -- ${15\choose 4}{10\choose1}$

(3 red, 2 white) -- ${15\choose 3}{10\choose2}$